# ASP MVC Layout Page does not run custom JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on a new project and therefore used a boilerplate ([this one](http://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-mvc-boilerplate/))
For some reason the custom javascript I add in my _Layout page does not run.

This is what I have on the bottom of my body tag :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryvalunobtrusive")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tether")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/search.js") ==> Works aswell
<script type="text/javascript"> ==> Does not work
    alert("loading");
</script>
@RenderSection("JavaScript", false)
```

Everything works from external files except the alert. If I inspect my website I see that the code is added :

All of the JavaScript in my other views that I place inside a section does not work aswell :

```
@section JavaScript
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("test");
        $().ready(function () {
            console.log("view");
            alert("test");
       });
    </script>
}
```

I have no idea whats wrong. Never had this before. Any help is much appreciated.

Thx!

Comment: It can be either a javascript error that cause the rest of the code is not executed (any js error in developer tools?) or one (or more) bundles are not bundled correctly. What happens when you try to load the bundle js directly?

Comment: Agreed, a js error in one of the bundles is the likeliest explanation - the dev tools console should point you in the right direction, but you can do some simple debugging by moving your alert code above all of the bundles to see if it works, and then move it in between the bundles until you find the culprit.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. If I load a external JS file with code after all the bundles this does runs perfectly. I don't get any errors either in my developer.

Comment: Can you add the outputted code to your question? At least the section around your `alert` code. Also, can you try adding the alert _on top_ of the other scripts?

Comment: Hi @tocqueville, I don't understand your first question but if I add the alert on top of the other scripts (in the beginning) it does not work aswell. I am clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by the maker of the boilerplate :

"You need to read about Content Security Policy (CSP). Inline scripts are blocked by default as a security feature."